# Replace values of rows with missing values by values of another row

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, conditional-statements, na

I’m trying to work with conditional but don’t find an easy way to do it.
I have a dataset with missing value in column As, I want to create a new column C that takes the original values in A for all the rows without missing, and for row with missing value take the value from another column (column B).
All columns are character variables.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 13 A 1 | 15 A 2 |
| 15 A 2 | 15 A 2 |
| NA | 15 A 8 |
| 10 B 3 | 15 A 2 |
| NA | 15 A 5 |

What i want is:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 A 1 | 15 A 2 | 13 A 1 |
| 15 A 2 | 15 A 2 | 15 A 2 |
| NA | 15 A 8 | 15 A 8 |
| 10 B 3 | 15 A 2 | 10 B 3 |
| NA | 15 A 5 | 15 A 5 |

I tried with a loop but the result is not satisfactory,

```
for(i in 1:length(df$A)) {
  if(is.na(df$A[i])) {
    df$C <- df$B 
  }
  else {
    df$C<- df$A
  }
}
```

If anyone can help me,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you find yourself looping over a data frame, there is probably a more efficient solution, either to use vectorised functions like
Jonathan has in his answer, or to use `dplyr` as follows.

We can check if `a` is `NA` - if so, we set `c` equal to `b`, otherwise keep it as `a`.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate(c = if_else(is.na(A), B, A))
```

```
       A      B      c
1 13 A 1 15 A 2 13 A 1
2 15 A 2 15 A 2 15 A 2
3   <NA> 15 A 8 15 A 8
4 10 B 3 15 A 2 10 B 3
5   <NA> 15 A 5 15 A 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
df$C <- ifelse(is.na(df$A), df$B, df$A)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(c = coalesce(A, B))
```

```
       A      B      c
1 13 A 1 15 A 2 13 A 1
2 15 A 2 15 A 2 15 A 2
3   <NA> 15 A 8 15 A 8
4 10 B 3 15 A 2 10 B 3
5   <NA> 15 A 5 15 A 5
```